# decoding json string with json.loads in python

Tags: python, json

I have string like that:

`jstring = {"label":"2017-06-01","value1":"250.730000"},{"label":"2017-06-02","value1":"250.730000"}`

end if I use json.loads(jstring) I got this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Funds.py", line 44, in <module>
    data  = json.loads(array)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/__init__.py", line 339, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/json/decoder.py", line 367, in decode
    raise ValueError(errmsg("Extra data", s, end, len(s)))
ValueError: Extra data: line 1 column 45 - line 1 column 54951 (char 44 - 54950)
```

What should I do with it?

Comment: Try surrounding your jstring with brackets, like `[{
 "label": "2017-06-01",
 "value1": "250.730000"
}, {
 "label": "2017-06-02",
 "value1": "250.730000"
}]`

Comment: I add [ , ] brackets but still won't run properly
Edit in the end of a string ';' appear so it wasn't correct, sorry for my mistake

Answer (score 1):

If you have the whole thing as on string like this:

```
jstring = '{"label":"2017-06-01","value1":"250.730000"},{"label":"2017-06-02","value1":"250.730000"}'
```

then the dumps process sees this as two differnt objects and it can't process the information correctly. you need to put your string in a single object like this:

```
jstring = '{"first":{"label":"2017-06-01","value1":"250.730000"},"second":{"label":"2017-06-02","value1":"250.730000"}}'
```

or like this:

```
jstring = '[{"label":"2017-06-01","value1":"250.730000"},{"label":"2017-06-02","value1":"250.730000"}]'
```

that way the parser sees only one object